# Understanding !d command in sed with respect to saves

Tags: sed

I have a directory of tab-delimited text files and some have comments in the first few lines that I would like to delete. I *know* that the first good line starts with "Mark" so I can use `/^Mark/,$!d` to delete these comments. After this deletion I have several other replacements that I make in the (new) first line that has variable names.

My question is, why do I have to save `sed`'s output to get my script to work? I understand that if I line is deleted, then the output doesn't proceed downstream because there is no output. But if I *don't* delete (i.e., `!d`) then why do I have to save to file? Thanks!

Here is my shell script. (I'm a `sed` newbie, so any other feedback is also appreciated.)

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.txt; do
    mv $file $file.old1
    sed -e '/^Mark/,$!d' $file.old1 > $file.old2
    sed -e '1s/\([Ss]\)hareholder/\1hrhldr/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Ii]\)mmediate/\1mmdt/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Nn]\)umber/\1o/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Cc]\)ompany/\1o/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Ii]\)nformation/\1nfo/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Pp]\)ercentage/\1ct/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Dd]\)omestic/\1om/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Gg]\)lobal/\1lbl/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Cc]\)ountry/\1ntry/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Ss]\)ource/\1rc/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Oo]\)wnership/\1wnrshp/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Uu]\)ltimate/\1ltmt/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Ii]\)ncorporation/\1ncorp/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Tt]\)otal/\1ot/g'\
        -e '1s/\([Dd]\)irect/\1ir/g'\
        $file.old2 > $file
        rm -f $file.old*
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sponge` is possible the safest way to overwrite your input file. `sponge` handles associated links to the file properly, `sed -i` doesn't. see this link: *[Is there a way to modify a file in-place?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-place)*

Test file

```
echo "comment
comment
Mark Global Ownership
Shareholder
Domestic
Last line" >test.txt
file=test.txt
cat "$file"
echo =====
```

The script without the loop.. (Just add the loop)

```
sed -n '/^Mark/,${  # check for "first time"
          G         # append the hold space, looking for "\nX" 
          /\n$/{    # nothing in the hold space, so "first time"
            s/\n$// # remove \n introduced by G
            s/\([Ss]\)hareholder/\1hrhldr/g
            s/\([Ii]\)mmediate/\1mmdt/g
            s/\([Nn]\)umber/\1o/g
            s/\([Cc]\)ompany/\1o/g
            s/\([Ii]\)nformation/\1nfo/g
            s/\([Pp]\)ercentage/\1ct/g
            s/\([Dd]\)omestic/\1om/g
            s/\([Gg]\)lobal/\1lbl/g
            s/\([Cc]\)ountry/\1ntry/g
            s/\([Ss]\)ource/\1rc/g
            s/\([Oo]\)wnership/\1wnrshp/g
            s/\([Uu]\)ltimate/\1ltmt/g
            s/\([Ii]\)ncorporation/\1ncorp/g
            s/\([Tt]\)otal/\1ot/g
            s/\([Dd]\)irect/\1ir/g
            p           # print
            s/.*/X/; h  # set a "flag" in the hold space 
            b           # branch unconditionally (ie, next)
          };
          P;b   # print line (before "\nX") and branch            
        };d' "$file" | sponge "$file"

cat "$file"
```

The output

```
comment
comment
Mark Global Ownership
Shareholder
Domestic
Last line
=====
Mark Glbl Ownrshp
Shareholder
Domestic
Last line
```

Comment: Wow. Maybe it's easier to do the file write :). I guess I'm just puzzled why I have to write to file when I'm _not_ deleting. There are lots of good tricks here for me. Thanks!

Comment: Technically you may not need to, but it is fiddly and fraught with the "unexpected" (like when it needs to be modified for longer text), and (technically) sed just doesn't work that way; it is a text Stream EDitor, designed as per the *nix* paradigm of *"do one thing and do it well"* (and then pipe it to something else).. But, really, the overhead is not that great, you still need to write the data (all of it after the first changed byte) and then 1 file delete and 1 file rename.. On the other hand, running `sed` twice sequentially per file is definite *overhead* ...(sed | sed is reasonable).

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to save the standard ouput to a file. You can pipe(`|`) the output to the next `sed` process. Other option is to use `sed`'s `edit in place` option(`-i`)

From [**man sed**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed),

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
    edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

Comment: Thanks! If I run every command as `-ie` will it run _really_ slow? It seems that would write to file after every operation?